# how to apply different Images to DataGridViewImageColumn in Windows form

Tags: winforms, image, datagridview

I am using DataGridView ,in which I have dynamically created an Image Column ,I want to diplay Pass and fail Images in this column depeending on the condition below is the code,

DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();

```
                    img.Name = "img";
                    img.HeaderText = "Image Column";



                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(img);

                    int number_of_rows = dataGridView1.RowCount;

                    for (int i = 0; i < (number_of_rows - 1); i++)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "Pass")
                        {

                            Image image = global::Instore.Properties.Resources.pass;
                            img.Image = image;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["img"].Value = image;

                        }
                        else if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "Fail")
                        {
                            Image image2 = global::Instore.Properties.Resources.fail;
                            img.Image = image2;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["img"].Value = image2;


                        }
                    }
```

I have attach the code when I am running it its showing Pass.png in all the rows whereas it should show fail image in some of the rows..

Kindly help...

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 1):

Remove these two lines:

```
img.Image = image;

...

img.Image = image2;
```